# Как создать шаблон формы на Yii

Tags: php, yii

Хочется из базы гибко настраивать шаблон ввода формы для Yii.

Например шаблон Пользователь - поля Логин(text), Пароль(text), Возраст (int).

Шаблон Админ -  поля Логин(text), Пароль(text), Должность (int), Последний вход (timestamp).

То есть не создавать отдельные таблицы и формы, а указывать шаблон, где хранится информация о имени поля, его типе, возможно другая информация (ссылка на таблицу например).

В принципе можно и просто запросом это вытягивать и циклом выводить поля. Но как в таком случае указать дефолтную валидацию для типа?

Я слышал про конструктор форм, можно его использовать в данном случае? То есть самый главный вопрос - как прикрутить валидацию "из коробки" к полям не из модели?

```
echo '<div class="column">';
echo CHtml::label($rows[$i]['name'], $rows[$i]['name']);
echo CHtml::textField("elem[$id]", $val, array('id' => "id[$id]"));
echo '</div>';
```

Что-то вроде ролей

```
array('name', 'required'),
array('dep_id, user_id, factory_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly' => true),
```

Comment: Какую валидацию вы имеете ввиду, серверную или клиентскую?

Comment: клиентскую. хотя можно и свои конечно костыли на js накидать, но это вряд ли будет красиво

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Варианта может быть два.

1. Если вы просто описываете шаблон формы для существующих моделей, в существующих моделях описываете валидацию.
   Информацию на эти тему хватает -  [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/155127/), [тут](http://www.yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/form.builder) или [есть вот компонент](https://github.com/yiiext/form-component)
2. Вы описываете свой класс на основе [CFormModel](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFormModel) и реализуете свои методы сохранения и обновления данных

   ```
   class TemplatesModel extends CFormModel{

   public $template = null;

   public function init()
   {
       if($this->scenario){
           //Ищем в сохраненный шаблон
           $model = Templates::model()->findByAttribytes(['name'=>$this->scenario]);
           if($model){
               //Сохраняем его в переменную
               $this->template = $model;
           }else{
               //обрабатываете ошибку
           }
       }
   }

   public function rules(){
       $rules = [];
       //формируете массив правил для валидации из базы
       if($this->template['rules'] && ($rules = unserialize($this->template['rules']))){
           foreach($rules as $rule){
               $rules[] = ... ;
           }
       }
       return $rules;
   }

   public function attributes(){
       $attributes=[];
       //формируете массив аттрибутов
       return $attributes;
   }

   // реализуете метод сохранения
   public function save($validate=true){
       if($validate && $this->validate){
           //сохраняем данные
           return true; // false смотря как сохранится
       }else{
           return false;
       }
   }

   //Так же переопределяем методы __get() и __set(), условно выглядит примерно так
   public function __get($property)
   {
       return $this->template['attributes'][$property]
   }

   public function __set($property, $val)
   {
       $this->template['attributes'][$property] = $val;
   }
   }
   ```

Дальше будете работать просто как с моделью:

```
$model = new TemplatesModel('user'); // указываем название шаблона в scenario
```

Но для постройки форм все равно будете использовать конструктор